# What mean : the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ determines how they depend linearly of each other?

Tags: probability

**Q1)** In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), they say that the correlation *refers to the degree to which a pair of variables are linearly related*. What do they mean by "linearly related" ? For example, I can see that $Y=kX$ for $k\neq 0$ will gives a correlation of $\pm 1$. But now, what would look a r.v. $Y=f(X)$ such that $0<Corr(X,Y)<1$ ? $f$ will be near to be linear ? How would look this sort of function ?

**Q2)** Is there a sort of correlation that describe how random variables are quadratically related ? (for example $Y=X^2$ would off a quadratic correlation $1$).

Comment: Adressing Q2: Just linearize, that is determine the correlation  between $Y$ and $X^2$ instead of $Y$ and $X$.

Answer (score 1):

For Q1), something as $f(x)=\alpha x+g(x)$ where $\alpha \neq 0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded should work (think to $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$).

For Q2) what about $$\text{Corr}_{2}(X,Y)=\text{Corr}(X^2,Y)\ \ ?$$